# How to reference a variable inside a class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

Was hoping someone could help me in trying to print a class method's variable. As show below in my code, I want to print variable A of the method "on_status", which is part of my class MyStreamListener. Is this possible? Bit of a noob question...appreciate any insight. Thank you!

```
Y = 0
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api=None, **options):
        self.api = api
        self.retry_time_start = options.get("retry_time", 5.0)
        self.retry_420_start = options.get("retry_420", 60.0)

    def on_connect(self):
        pass

    def on_status(self, status):
        X = '@' + status.user.screen_name + ' - ' + status.text
        if not any(badword in X for badword in badwords):
            print(X)
            print(status.created_at)
            self.A = status.user.screen_name



    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            Y = 1


myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
# async parameter on filter will allow stream to run on a new thread when connection is closed and old thread is blocked
while True:

    if Y != 1:
        print(myStream.filter(track=['test'], async = True))
        --- WANT TO PRINT VARIABLE A HERE ---
```

Comment: Assuming that `on_status` has already been called, just do `print(myStream.A)`.

Comment: The method might not be executed, so the variable can't exist. The same applies when the condition inside the method is not met.

Comment: this is a plain instance-method, not a `classmethod`

Comment: Note: `Y = 1` in `on_error()` will not change the global `Y` without a `global` declaration, so `Y` will never equal `1`. However, I would recommend against `global` and just make `Y` an instance variable too. It is best practice to initialize your variables in `__init__()`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not describe your class's ordinary methods as "class methods". In Python, as "class method" is a method that is called on a class, rather than on an object of a class. Such methods are defined using the [`@classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), and take as their first parameter the class (named `cls` by convention) rather than an object (named `self` by convention). (So a `MyStreamListener` class method could be called as either `MyStreamListener.my_class_method()`, or as `myStreamListener.my_class_method()`, where `myStreamListener` is an object of type `MyStreamListener`.)

Secondly, if you assign a variable `self.A` within a method, that variable belongs to the object, not the method, and can be accessed anywhere where the object is available, as `object_var.A`, where `object_var` is a variable holding the object. If you're inside a method, then you would use `self.A`. If you're in client code that has just instantiated your class as `myStreamListener`, then you would use `myStreamListener.A`.

Thirdly, if you will be accessing `A` from outside `on_status`, where it might not have been initialised yet, you should initialise it with some sensible value in `__init__`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the critique and feedback, appreciate it greatly.

Comment: the only issue here is that the tweepy API im using gets my variable A from the on_status method. I don't know how I could initialize in init

Comment: For example, you could initialise with `self.A = None` in `__init__`, which would mean that an attempt to read `A` before it had been written to would return `None`, rather than raising an `AttributeError` exception. What behaviour are you expecting if you attempt to print `A` when `on_status` has only been called with a `status` that contains anything in `badwords`? (I.e. So when `A` has not been set.) That will determine how you should handle the possibility of an uninitialised `A`.